# $_POST is empty in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to ***var_dump($_POST);*** on the same page as the form is and all i get is an empty array.

Why is ***$_POST*** empty?
I cant see the values that was posted with the form.

```
<form name="car_form" id="car_form" method="post" action="" >
<input type="text" name="brand">
<input type="text" name="color">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add car" class="button">
</form>
```

Comment: Do you see anything when you `var_dump($_REQUEST);`? Also, take a look at the network tab in your browser's dev tools when you click the submit button. Does the request look right (i.e. the list of fields/values in the POST request body)?

Comment: @IanDrake var_dump($_REQUEST); just has the GET params from the url. In the Network tab i can see the form data.

Comment: I definitely think WordPress is interfering, possibly redirecting your request after you click submit, which would cause the POST data to get lost (you can probably see this in the network tab). You might want to look at this for one possible solution: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/246199. Another workaround might be to just use GET, if you think that will work for your form. Not ideal, but it might allow you to simply avoid the problem.

Comment: @IanDrake i can see that the Status Code is 302 in the Network tab. Does this have something to do with the problem? I really dont want to use GET for posting the form :)

Comment: Yeah, that means WordPress is definitely doing a redirect, which explains why the POST data is getting lost. I think I know enough to post an answer here shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/246199), here's some code that I think will work for your situation. First the form code. You'll notice I changed the action attribute to submit to `admin-post.php`, and I added 2 new fields to the form.

```
<form name="car_form" id="car_form" method="post" action="<?= admin_url('admin-post.php') ?>" >
    <input type="text" name="brand">
    <input type="text" name="color">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add car" class="button">

    <!-- 2 new fields -->
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="car_form">
    <?php wp_nonce_field('car_form_nonce', 'car_form_nonce'); ?>
</form>
```

Then, somewhere in PHP, you'll need to register a WP action to handle the POST request, and define the function that will be called when that action is triggered, which will look like this:

```
<?php
add_action('admin_post_nopriv_car_form', 'carFormSubmit');
add_action('admin_post_car_form', 'carFormSubmit');

function carFormSubmit() {
    var_dump($_POST); //$_POST variables should be accessible now

    //Optional: Now you can redirect the user to your confirmation page using wp_redirect()
}
```

If you're not 100% sure where that code goes, `functions.php` is a good default location. Note: I haven't tested this code, but it should be enough to get you started.

Unfortunately this is necessary to avoid WordPress redirecting your form submission and losing all of your POST data.

Comment: Is there a methods to access the $_POST in short code since you access it in the functions.php?

Comment: @StanPeng you would probably need to create a custom shortcode, for example: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90878/using-shortcodes-to-parse-post-request-containing-the-data-from-a-front-end-for